# syslog.conf configuration to log only into a custom log file,

Tags: c, linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I am using syslog in my application, I have  created a rule in syslog.conf file to log 
data from my application in to specific file.
But it is also writing in to the standard syslog file, i dont want that.
Can anybody please tell me to how to make it stop wrinting in the standard syslog file.

Comment: You need to ask this on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

The [rsyslog wiki has an example](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Filtering_by_program_name) of redirecting data to a specific file, and avoiding to log it anywhere else.

First a rule to redirect:

```
if <your rule> then <your log file>
```

Then the same rule with ~ as action, causing the log line not to go into other filters

```
if <your rule> then ~
```

Comment: I was able to get the required output by tweaking the conf file. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: user, Could you either edit your question or answer to help other people?